# Windows Active Directory Certificate Service: Is it possible to export private key from Issued Certificates created from custom request?

Tags: windows, x509certificate

On Windows AD CS Service, I have to create a certificate from Create Custom Request... option on the personal certificate store since templates are not available on standalone CAs.
[Create custom request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYHRd.png)

I made sure that export private key option is checked in the properties of the request:
[Certificate Request Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6vO7.png)

Now when, the request was submitted to CA and then certificate has been issued. There is no option to export the issued certificate with its private key (PKCS#12 PFX format).

Copy to file option has the options I need greyed out :(
[Export options/Save to file options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZwIU.png)

Please let me know if I am missing a step. Or what else could I check. Thank you so much!

I tried the find certificates functionality in the Certificates (Current User) but discovers that there is somewhat and intermediate copy there that can be exported with the private key, but the issuer is the same as the subject unlike the one on the issued.

Figure 1: Find certificate functionality can find the certificate but it is not quite right since the issuer is the one I am issuing the certificate to:[Find certificates in personal store...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SoQw.png)

Figure 2: Comparison between the certificate in the find cert... vs the one on the issued certificate. They have the same subject CN=CA2016 but different issuer:
[Find cert vs Issued Certs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AnzL.png)

What else have I tried?

- Tried everything on Windows Server Standard 2022 and Server Standard 2016.
- Tried making the request from Certificates (Local Computer)
- Tried one on domain environment

They have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The issued certificate must be imported to the personal store to get the cert and its private keys. Thank you self for discovering the solution. :p

[Solution: import to personal store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBtOf.png)